# Postgres SQL: New table with unique rows for all dates in date range

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

Looking for some guidance on where to begin with a query that is hurting my head.

I have a table that shows trial start & end dates for each account over time, looks something like this:

```
account_id  trial_start  trial_end
==========  ===========  =========
123         1/2/2017     1/9/17
234         1/8/2017     1/21/17
456         1/15/2017    5/10/17
```

The trial start and end dates vary and I want a resulting table that shows me each of the account IDs that were in a trial each week of the year. This way I can say how many active trials I had in each week of the year and do things like see how many of those accounts were actually being logged into during that week of their trial. Perhaps something like:

```
week         account_id
===========  =========
1/1/2017     123
1/8/2017     123
1/8/2017     234
1/15/2017    234
1/15/2017    456
1/22/2017    456
...
5/7/2017     456
```

I have a reference table that has a row for each week of the year and I feel like I need to somehow join my account IDs to each row in that table, but I can't figure out how I might map each week in between the start and end date to each week's row such that i'm capturing the dates in between :/

Comment: `OVERLAPS` seems to be a good candidate for `JOIN` condition as long as you know when your each week starts and ends.

Comment: add a few rows from your weeks table please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form a Cartesian product of accounts and weeks, then place the week staring date amongst the trail dates (this will pickup each week involved).

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9fb0e/4)

**PostgreSQL 9.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TrialDates
    (account_id int, trial_start timestamp, trial_end timestamp)
;

INSERT INTO TrialDates
    ("account_id", "trial_start", "trial_end")
VALUES
    (678, '2017-01-04 00:00:00', '2017-01-05 00:00:00'),
    (123, '2017-01-02 00:00:00', '2017-01-09 00:00:00'),
    (234, '2017-01-08 00:00:00', '2017-01-21 00:00:00'),
    (456, '2017-01-15 00:00:00', '2017-05-10 00:00:00')
;


CREATE TABLE Weeks
    ("week_start" timestamp)
;

INSERT INTO Weeks
    ("week_start")
VALUES
    ('2017-01-16 00:00:00'),
    ('2017-01-09 00:00:00'),
    ('2017-01-02 00:00:00')
;
```

**Query 1**: (*edited*)

```
select  w.week_start, td.account_id
from (select distinct account_id from TrialDates) a
cross join Weeks w
inner join TrialDates td on a.account_id = td.account_id
and (
      w.week_start >= td.trial_start and w.week_start < trial_end
    OR
      td.trial_start >= w.week_start and td.trial_start < w.week_start + interval '7 days'
    )   
order by  w.week_start, td.account_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9fb0e/4/0)**:

```
|           week_start | account_id |
|----------------------|------------|
| 2017-01-02T00:00:00Z |        123 |
| 2017-01-02T00:00:00Z |        234 |
| 2017-01-02T00:00:00Z |        678 |
| 2017-01-09T00:00:00Z |        234 |
| 2017-01-09T00:00:00Z |        456 |
| 2017-01-16T00:00:00Z |        234 |
| 2017-01-16T00:00:00Z |        456 |
```

### added

For readers who might not have an existing weeks table, the same result can be achieved by using the really excellent `generate_series` functionality of PostgreSQL. So below the cross join of weeks is dynamically generated with the lower and upper boundary dates of the series also dynamically determined.

```
select  w.week_start, td.account_id
from (select distinct account_id from TrialDates) a
cross join (
      select
          date_trunc('week', dates.d) as week_start
      from generate_series(
              (select date_trunc('week',min(trial_start)) from TrialDates)
             , 
              (select date_trunc('week',max(trial_start) + interval '6 days') from TrialDates)
             , '1 day'
             ) as dates(d)
      group by 1
      ) w
inner join TrialDates td on a.account_id = td.account_id
and (
      w.week_start >= td.trial_start and w.week_start < trial_end
    OR
      td.trial_start >= w.week_start and td.trial_start < w.week_start + interval '7 days'
    )       
order by  w.week_start, td.account_id
;
```

Comment: Please note this answer has changed to include logic for a short duration trial (see account_id 678 in the data) so he join conditions alter to cover that situation.